# Python using tkinter wont write to database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have created a log in and registration system, where a user inputs their first and surname, password, and whether they are a teacher or student by pressing a button. However, none of the inputs are recorded to the database tables, and it ends up coming empty, and you can log in to four different accounts by leaving both entries blank as the 4 attempts I tried all count as 4 empty accounts

```
def teachertype():
    var_usertype = ("Teacher")

def studenttype():
    var_usertype = ("Student")

def register():
    global screen2
    global var_FName
    global var_SName
    global var_password1
    global var_usertype
    var_FName = str()
    var_SName = str()
    var_password1 = str()
    var_usertype = str()

    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("Registration")
    screen2.geometry("500x500")
    Label(screen2, text = "Please enter your username and password below: ").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "Firstname: ").pack()
    Entry(screen2, textvariable = var_FName).pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "Surname: ").pack()
    Entry(screen2, textvariable = var_SName).pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "Password: ").pack()
    Entry(screen2, textvariable = var_password1).pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen2, text = "Teacher", width = 10, height = 1, command = teachertype).pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen2, text = "Student", width = 10, height = 1, command = studenttype).pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen2, text = "Register", width = 10, height = 1, command = regfunc).pack()

def regfunc():
    var_insert = []
    var_insert.append(var_FName)
    var_insert.append(var_SName)
    var_insert.append(str(var_password1))
    userID = var_FName[0:3] + var_SName
    var_insert.append(userID)
    var_insert.append(var_usertype)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('insert INTO users (FName, SName, password, username, userType)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);', var_insert)
    conn.commit()
    Label(screen2, text = "Successfully registered! Your username to log in is "+userID+"", fg = "GREEN", font = "Calibri")
    login()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, var_insert should be a tuple not a list.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html